# swift 4 How to i fetch all users except current user

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4

Acually I have a code for fetch user from firebase 3. But  need to fetch all users except current one. In my new messages controller, I would like fetch users.

```
func fetchUser() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let user = User()

            user.id = snapshot.key
            user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            user.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
            user.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
            let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


            self.users.append(user)


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What's your data structure look like? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
func fetchUserExceptCurrent() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let user = User()

            user.id = snapshot.key
            user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            user.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
            user.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
            let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

            let currentUserID : String = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)! //get current user id

            //Filter current user
            if user.id != currentUserID {
                self.users.append(user)
            } else {
                debugPrint("Current user filtered")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: let currentUser: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
                //Filter current user
                if user.id != currentUser {
                    self.users.append(user)
                } else {
                    debugPrint("Current user filtered")

Comment: Glad it helped.